# Accessing one erlang module by another when in different folders

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I have a pretty simple doubt, but I can't seem to find a proper solution for it anywhere.
I have 2 erlang modules, `module1.erl` and `module2.erl`. As defined by the submission guidelines for my project, both modules belong to different parts and are hence in different folders part1 and part2 respectively under the same directory. This is how the structure looks:

```
src/
   part1/
       module1.erl
   part2/
       module2.erl
```

Now module2 is dependent on module1, and calls various methods of module1 as `module1:method()`. I'm able to achieve full functionality when both `module1.erl` and `module2.erl` are in the same folder, but now they're in different folders, and I try to run `module2.erl` from part2 folder, I can't figure out how to allow module2 to compile and call the methods of module1.

Comment: What is the command you are using to run this code? Or are you trying to load the modules one by one in the terminal ?

Comment: I just start an era shell inside part2 and try to run `c(module2).` and then `module2:method().`. I'm unable to run `c(module1).` because it's not located in the same folder, which is another one of the issues I'm facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the emulator is being used, the path to `module1` is not in the ***[code path](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/code.html#code-path)*** by default when we are launching the emulator in the path of `module2` directly and with default options. This can be verified using ...

```erlang
1> code:get_path().
code:get_path().
[".","/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/kernel-8.2/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/stdlib-3.17/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/xmerl-1.3.28/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/wx-2.1.1/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/tools-3.5.2/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/tftp-1.0.3/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/syntax_tools-2.6/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/ssl-10.6/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/ssh-4.13/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/snmp-5.11/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/sasl-4.1.1/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/runtime_tools-1.17/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/reltool-0.9/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/public_key-1.11.3/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/parsetools-2.3.2/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/os_mon-2.7.1/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/odbc-2.13.5/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/observer-2.10.1/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/mnesia-4.20.1/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/megaco-4.2/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/inets-7.5/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/hipe-4.0.1/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/ftp-1.1/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/eunit-2.7/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/et-1.6.5/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/erts-12.2/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/erl_interface-5.1/ebin",
 [...]|...]
```

This list has `.` in it, but not `../part1`, so when when we are compiling, been in the `part2` directory, it fails...

```erlang
2> c(module1).
c(module1).
{error,non_existing}
```

There are several ways to work around this, few simple ones could be...

1. `c("../part1/module1.erl").`. As per the documentation of [`c`](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/c.html#c-1)

> ***...Module can be either a module name or a source file path, with or without .erl extension...***

And here, in the option above, we used the relative path to the source file of `module1`.

2. Invoke `erl` with an option [***`-pa`***](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html) which adds the path of `part1` in the code path for that session of the `erlang emulator`.

```erlang
part2$ erl -pa "../part1"
Erlang/OTP 25 [DEVELOPMENT] [erts-12.2] [source-c1ab4b5424] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:1] [jit:ns]

Eshell V12.2  (abort with ^G)
1> code:get_path().
["../part1",".","/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/kernel-8.2/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/stdlib-3.17/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/xmerl-1.3.28/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/wx-2.1.1/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/tools-3.5.2/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/tftp-1.0.3/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/syntax_tools-2.6/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/ssl-10.6/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/ssh-4.13/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/snmp-5.11/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/sasl-4.1.1/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/runtime_tools-1.17/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/reltool-0.9/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/public_key-1.11.3/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/parsetools-2.3.2/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/os_mon-2.7.1/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/odbc-2.13.5/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/observer-2.10.1/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/mnesia-4.20.1/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/megaco-4.2/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/inets-7.5/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/hipe-4.0.1/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/ftp-1.1/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/eunit-2.7/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/et-1.6.5/ebin",
 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/erts-12.2/ebin",
 [...]|...]
2> c(module2).
{ok,module2}
3> c(module1).
Recompiling /home/nalin/source/erlang/part2/../part1/module1.erl
{ok,module1}
4> module2:exec().
"Module2"
5> module1:exec().
"Module1"
6>
```

I hope this much should be sufficient to get you going. Also, you must take an opportunity to read through the [Compilation and Code Loading](https://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/code_loading.html) to have some idea around what goes on.

---

---

***`WYSIWYG`*** => ***`WHAT YOU SHOW IS WHAT YOU GET`***

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful and solves my problem :)